# jquery date picker set date format as 'MM-DD-YYYY' from a string containing datetime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to set the jquery datepicker date format but it is not working, I have read few posts and answer already but none of them worked for me. Below is the code I am using please check and tell me where I am doing wrong. I am getting the datetime from Database as `2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat:'MM-DD-YYYY'
            }).val();
        });
    </script>
```

Also I tried

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dateTypeVar = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
            $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dateTypeVar);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: _" I am getting the datetime from Database as 2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC"_ I'm failing to see why that's pertinent.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This `2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC` is not a valid JavaScript date, so the `datepicker` can't accept the value assigned.

`Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

`setDate` method: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Get the date in a compliant format, and then set the `datepicker` in this way.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dbDate = "2012-03-06";
    var date2 = new Date(dbDate);

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    }).datepicker('setDate', date2)

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7ck7D/

Comment: But. why is the date a day below? 5th instead of the 6th?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date2 = new Date().getDate()-9;

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }).datepicker('setDate', date2)

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7ck7D/

Comment: Please describe why you use `-9` ?

Comment: This is a good answer, code-wise.  It could be improved by explaining what you've done and/or explain why what the OP has done did not work.

Comment: Also, your answer does not match your jsfiddle